# FaceDetectionListener onFaceDetection not called

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, face-detection

I'm writing an app that uses the camera preview to detect faces. My device can detect faces, the listener is set and face detection is started (in that order), but onFaceDetection is never called. I have subclassed SurfaceView as the view that shows the camera preview.

The listener is laid out just after all the activity's variable declarations:

```
FaceDetectionListener fdl = new FaceDetectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
        Log.d("CameraViewApp", "Faces detected.");
    }
}
```

When the user tells the app to show that view holding the camera view, before the view is shown on screen, this is done:

```
cameraview = new CameraView(context);
Log.d("CameraViewApp", "Setting face detection listener.");
cameraview.setFaceDetectionListener(fdl);
rlMain.addView(cvGame, 0); //Adds cameraview to main view, "behind" everything else.
...
cameraview.startCamera();
setContentView(rlMain);
```

Here's the code for the startCamera() method of the CameraView class:

```
public void startCamera() {
    this.getHolder().addCallback(shcb);
    this.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    this.camera = Camera.open(0);
}
```

And the callback:

```
private SurfaceHolder.Callback shcb = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (camera != null) camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if(camera != null) {
            Size sizePreview = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, camera.getParameters()); //Custom method to find best preview size.
            parameters.setPreviewSize(sizePreview.width, sizePreview.height);
            requestLayout();

            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();

            if (fdl != null && camera.getParameters().getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0) {
                Log.d("CameraViewApp", "Starting face detection.");
                camera.startFaceDetection();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopFaceDetection();
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
};
```

"Setting face detection listener" appears in the LogCat followed by "Starting face detection" appearing in the LogCa, but "Faces detected" never appears in the LogCat. I've tried pointing the camera at pictures of faces on my screen, I've tried pointing the camera at my own face and I've tried switching to the front-facing camera so I can make sure my own face in is view and onFaceDetection is never called.

Answer (score 2):

This was a classic case of my own stupid fault. I had a custom method for setting the face detection listener in my custom CameraView class, but I wasn't setting the actual listener within that custom method. So keep an eye on your custom shenanigans, guys. :p